# Gloabally declared properties are not accessible from one functions to another in angular12

Tags: angular, properties, global

I have two globall properties define outside both functions.
result_quantity:any
current_value:any='30'
update_quantity:any

in first functionA(){
// i assign the subscribe result of observable to first property result_quantity and subtract it from current_value property and then assign this to update_quantity
}
functionB(){
then in second function of same class i wants to access this update_quantity property but its show me 'undefine'
}
Here is my full code

```
 result_quantity:any 
 current_value:any='30'
 update_quantity:any
 public getProductQuantity(){
    if(this.service.form.valid)
    this.prodid=this.service.form.value.ProductID;
    this.service.getProductQuantity(this.prodid).subscribe((result)=>{    
    this.result_quantity=result.quantity;
    this.updatequantity=this.result_quantity-this.current_value;
    })
  }
  updateProduct(){
    console.warn("updatequantity shows undefined in console",this.updatequantity)
      this.orderObj.ProductID=this.service.form.value.ProductID; 
      this.service.updateOder(this.orderObj.ProductID,this.newquatity).subscribe((result)=>{
     })
  }
```

Please help me to how to access this property in another function

Comment: No the update_quantity have alerady value in it, i had checked in console but when i wants to call this property in another function then it will not accessbible showing undefined

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be that `this.updatequantity=this.result_quantity-this.current_value;` is never called . So the update_quantity is never set to any value. Is the value of update quantity being updated anywhere before you call the second function?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).